# Live preview of formatted HTML form input with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, live-preview

I want a feature of previewing some text with HTML tags and then storing the text in database. I know it is not a good idea to allow HTML in database, for XSS security reasons. What are the ways to achieve this?

I want a feature similar to the one we have in stackoverflow, where we can format our sourcecodes. Thanks.

Comment: stackoverflow uses `Markdown` as markup system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Recommended way:**

Create an [javascript event listener](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/Observer/) for the form on your html-page. Submit the input [via ajax to your rails app](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/), where the input gets rendered (for example by the same helper that will later render the output from the database).

Use a markup language like [RedCloth/Textile](http://redcloth.org/textile) to avoid XSS. It's also easier to type/understand for your users!

**Your requested way:**

Create an javascript event listener and write the contents of the form/input to another div.

The javascript you'll need depends on which library you use (Prototype or jQuery, for example).

**Example:**

Suppose you have a form with a textarea, `<textarea id="text"></textarea>`, and a preview area div with `<div id="preview"></div>` and you are using Prototype:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  new Form.Element.Observer('text', 0.25, 
    function () {
      $('preview').update($F('text'));
    }
  );
}
```

This will check the textarea every 250ms for changes and copy its input into the preview div.

Actually, you just need the code inside the function that is called with `document.observe` (starting with `new Form.Element.Observer...`. The `document.observe` will call this code after the browser has finished building the DOM-tree.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using something like textile or markdown, which are ways to achieve HTML markup with plain text.